# Change Cordova Windows 8 Application to run in web context instead of local context

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, cordova

I have a Phonegap/Cordova application I'm building and I'm using jQuery's $.get() function to retrieve API information. This works in iOS but it's not in Windows and it throws the following error.

> An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.

How can I convert app to run in the web context?

My code is as follows:

```
    function sync_disclaimer_api_call() {

    // do we have an internet connection?
    if ( ( network_state == "none" ) || ( network_state == "unknown" )  ) {

        // do nothing

    } else {

        // what to send as get vars 
        fields = {};
        fields.data         = some_data;

        // ping API with information
        $.get(
            the_url_i_am_trying_to_get, 
            fields,
            function( result ) {

                // did we get "ok" status from API?
                if ( result.status.toString() == 'ok' ) {

                    // we're good
                    if ( result.selector && result.content ) {
                        // do something
                    }

                } else {

                    // error - dont do anything
                }

            },
            "jsonp"
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you.